# DBLookupComboBox - how to filter by typing similar select2 jquery

Tags: delphi

How do I filter on typing DBLookupComboBox, and search for the word contained in any position of the item, similar to the jquery select2.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't Type in the `DBLookupComboBox`, but you can use it with a `TEdit` and `TPanel`.

- Place a `TPanel`.
- Place a  `TDBLookupComboBox` and a `TEdit` on the `TPanel` and set `Align` property of both of them to `alClient`.
- Use this `procedure`.
- Set the `AlignWithMargins` property of the `TEdit` to `True`.
- Edit the `Top, Buttom, Right` to 0 and set the `Right` to 20.
- Use the `procedure` for the filter.

  ```
  Procedure filterr(Dataset: TDataSet; const FieldName, SearchTerm: string);
  begin
  Assert(Assigned(Dataset), 'No dataset is assigned');

  if SearchTerm = '' then
  Dataset.Filtered := False
  else
  begin
  Dataset.Filter := FieldName + ' LIKE ' + QuotedStr(SearchTerm + '*');
  Dataset.Filtered := True;
  end;
  end;
  ```
- In the `OnChange` event of the `TEdit`

  ```
  filterr(mytable;'fieldname';edit1.Text);
  ```

Comment: Thank you is exactly what I need.
A doubt: the DBLookupComboBox and Edit components do not have the alignment property.